# How to make a service remain alive if the application is destroy from the memory

Tags: java, android, service

The main thing i just want to do is that i have to check on me webservice when my application is closed when it gets any alert on webservice then it shows notification or activity.
I read about services and make an example but when i remove the application from recent apps then some time the service is restarted or some the service got killed to.

**Code:**

```
package com.usamaakmal.startedservice;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewService extends Service {
    public NewService() {
    }

    int i = 0;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Thread runnable = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i++;
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Hello World! " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,2000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing app from recent apps list kills app process. Returning `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()` means you want the system to restart the service after it was killed (either because you removed the app from recents list or system killed service because it ran out of resources).

If you want to keep your service (and it's process) alive you will need foreground service. 
System tries to keep foreground services alive as long as possible.
See: [Running service in foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)